# Creating a graph in GraphEdit to capture RTP video stream to a file

Tags: c#, video, stream, rtp, graphedit

I have a RTP video stream encoded in h.264 and I would like to capture it into a file.

I'm trying to create a graph in GraphEdit that will listen to a specific port (RTP stream) and will save it to a file.

If you know any good filters I can use or good guides I would love to try them.

Comment: Are you locked into using GraphEdit, or can you use other options? I can do this in Vlc.DotNet.

Answer (score 1):

MainConcept is good but not cheap.